# Change the value of the cookie or remove the cookie inside a jax-rs endpoint

Tags: java, web-services, cookies, jax-rs

I have a jax-rs endpoint. In side the endpoint I need to remove or change the existing value of an existing cookie. below I have mentioned my code.

```
@GET
@Path("/")
@Produces("text/html")
public String logout(@Context HttpServletRequest request, @QueryParam("logoutNotification") String logoutNotification,
                     @QueryParam("id_token_hint") String id_token_hint,@CookieParam("statusCookie") javax.ws.rs.core.Cookie cookie) {
    Response response=null;
    if(logoutNotification.equals("T")) {
        if (cookie != null) {
       //update the value of the statusCookie cookie or remove the existing statusCookie cookie
        }
        }
```

Somebody please help me to implement this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you can try something like this.

```
@GET
@Path(value = "/test")
public Response test(@CookieParam("statusCookie") javax.ws.rs.core.Cookie cookie) {
    NewCookie newCookie = null;
    if(cookie != null) {
        newCookie = new NewCookie("statusCookie", "second");
    } else {
        newCookie = new NewCookie("statusCookie", "first");
    }
    return Response.ok("test").cookie(newCookie).build();
}
```

first time check is cookie named `statusCookie` is exist if no it create a new cookie and set value to `first`. when `statusCookie` exist it also create a new cookie with same name and set value to `second` which is actually overwrite existing cookie value. because of same name.

Comment: Hi Mayank, Thanks for the response. It creates a new cookie with the same name. I need to update the existing cookie.

Comment: In case this is useful for anyone looking at this answer. you need to make sure the path of the cookie you a creating is the same as the original cookie. In this specific case the cookie with be created in the path "test". You will need to check if the original cookie was created in the same path. The easiest solution is to set the path parameter in the NewCookie constructor